# Creating a file to execute terminal commands on mac

Tags: bash, macos, terminal, google-cloud-storage, gsutil

I've recently bought a macbook and I am completely new to the whole Mac environment. I'm trying to recreate some automated processes I had on my old windows laptop. So here's my problem:

I use the terminal to download a file from my Google Cloud Storage using the gsutil command:

`gsutil cp gs://<bucket>/<file> <destination>`

This works and it gets me what I need. My question is: can I make a file that runs this and other commands through the terminal so that I don't have to open up the terminal every time?

I've tried to use the Automator app but it gets way too complicated because Automator doesn't have the same configurations needed that I have already settled in the terminal. I have also tried making a .bs file containing the following code:

```
#!/bin/sh

gsutil cp gs://<bucket>/<file> <destination>
```

But this doesn't help me because it just opens up Xcode when I click this file.

There has to be a simple way to make a file which executes some simple terminal commands right? I feel like I am missing something fundamental about macs and linux in general. If you have any idea how I can tackle this, please let me know.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What type of triggering is required to run this script?

Comment: did you make the script executable? `chmod +x myscript`

Comment: Can you follow the steps mentioned [here](https://support.apple.com/en-in/guide/terminal/apdd100908f-06b3-4e63-8a87-32e71241bab4/mac) and see if it works?